# How to get from Cuba to Costa Rica?

Tags: air-travel, planning, cuba, costa-rica

What is the best option to get from Cuba to Costa Rica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, 'best' is not a good question? Does that mean 'cheapest', 'fastest' or 'best scenery'?

It seems there is only one direct flight from Havana to San Jose, this is with [TACA Airlines](http://www.taca.com), a one way fare can be found for $350 US.

Alternatively you can fly to Cancun (Mexico), Managua (Nicaragua) or Panama City and then take [a bus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4502/1317).